# Linq Errors on ToList(), Any(), Count(), Sum()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am getting the following errors, they are all related to system.linq.  The strange thing is that the method seems to work sometimes, the errors are not happening consistently.

Count() Code:

```
using (var dbContext = new Entities(GlobalStuff.EntityConnection))
{
    heartBeat.NumSlipsInSecurityUploadQueue = dbContext.SecurityUploadQueues.Count();
    heartBeat.NumSlipsInDataStreamQueue = dbContext.DataStreamQueues.Count();
}
```

SecurityUploadQueues Property:

```
Public ReadOnly Property SecurityUploadQueues() As ObjectSet(Of SecurityUploadQueue)
        Get
            If (_SecurityUploadQueues Is Nothing) Then
                _SecurityUploadQueues = MyBase.CreateObjectSet(Of SecurityUploadQueue)("SecurityUploadQueues")
            End If
            Return _SecurityUploadQueues
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _SecurityUploadQueues As ObjectSet(Of SecurityUploadQueue)
```

The SecurityUploadQueue property is an EntityObject

Count() Error:

> Error Uploading HeartBeat System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<>c__11`1.b__11_3(IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
>      at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>      at SettlerService.SettlerService.UploadHeartBeat()

Any() Code:

```
var dataToUpload = (from bet in dbContext.DataStreamQueues select bet).Take(200);
if (dataToUpload.Any())
```

Any() Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified cast from a
>   materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Boolean' type is not
>   valid.   at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader
>   reader, Int32 ordinal) at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper
>   shaper) at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)   at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<>c__11`1.<GetElementFunction>b__11_3(IEnumerable`1
>   sequence)   at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot) 
>   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression) 
>   at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>   at SettlerService.SettlerService.UploadDataStream()

I've done some googling and can't find much on this issue.  I thought it might be related to the version of the system.core library (which system.linq is part of) but couldn't see an issue.  I am using .Net 4.7.2

Comment: You seem to be using Entity Framework. Sounds like you have some EF Mappings that need to be looked at.

Comment: You are correct, we are using Entity Framework 5.  What mapping would cause the errors?

Comment: How is `dbContext.SecurityUploadQueues` defined?

Comment: So the dbcontext is defined in a database first edmx file, SecurityUploadQueues is a table in the database

Comment: Judging by the error, it seems like the `SecurityUploadQueues` property is an `IQueryable` that's already contains an `Expression` and it might not point directly at the `DbSet<>`. But it's hard to tell without you showing the code

Comment: Ive updated the question to include detail about the SecurityUploadQueues property

Answer (score 0):

The **second** error implies that there is one columns in your `DataStreamQueues` database table with type of `Int32` but the type of the equivalent property in `DataStreamQueues` entity is bool; so check if all columns and properties types match.
Regarding the **first** exception, it's a bit strange! because this exception suggests that somewhere in your code you are calling Single() method on a set that has multiple items and as `Single()` expects only one item, it throws an exception, however I don't see any calls to `Single()` in the provided code.